# How to test Software Security?

Tags: security, testing

What are the **standards** and **testing methodologies** available to test security and vulnerabilities of a software application ?  ,

Characteristics of the application:

- Use public networks to transfer data
- Use Socket Programming
- Cryptography used
- Data Storing ethics and security ?

Comment: Read Schneier, he has a lot to say about weaknesses of *implementation* and human-level failings. We know the algorithms work, it's discipline that's the real problem. And to answer your question, there are very few practices which could be called "standard".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at OWASP. Lots of good info and links to other resources. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Principle